# How can I trace every event dispatched by a component or its descendants?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, events, flex3, event-handling

I am trying to determine what events I need to wait for in a test in order to ensure that my custom component has updated all of its properties. I was using VALUE_COMMIT, but for some reason that isn't working out for me.

So, I want some easy mechanism for tracing every event dispatched from a component. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your component (or one of its ancesors) is probably implementing the [IEventDispatcher interface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html) (right?).

You could override the dispatchEvent() method in your component like so:

```
override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
{
  trace(event.type);
  return super.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

This depends on the class you're extending. More info please :-)

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this (which struck me moments after asking the question).

I'd still like to see a solution that doesn't require code changes.